# Duda con herencia en SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, herencia

Tengo una duda con herencia de tablas en SQL;
Según he estado investigando se puede heredar tablas en SQL que compartan campos similares, por ejemplo estas 3 tablas;

```
*Persona: ID, Edad, Domicilio
Cliente:ID, Ultima compra
Empleado: ID, Departamento*
```

Una persona para un negocio puede ser tanto cliente, como un empleado, el cual ambos tienen una edad y un domicilio, pero lo que los diferencia es que el cliente tiene una fecha de ultima compra, y que el empleado pertenece a un departamento, "Comparten ciertos campos, pero tienen que los diferencie", ya solo se asocia el id de las tablas heredadas a la principal.

Mi pregunta es; ¿se puede heredar tablas por fecha?, me refiero a si tengo una tabla como la siguiente.

```
*Estados_de_cuenta:
ID, Cargo, Abono, Saldo, Fecha*
```

De esta haga una subtabla para colocar todos los IDs que fueron de Junio, otra para Agosto etc, Mi compañero me comento esto, pero segun estuve pensando todo se puede hacer en la misma tabla, y entre menos inner join haga en una consulta mas rapido sera el tiempo de busqueda (al menos en las pruebas que realice). ¿Funcionaria algo como la herencia en este caso o no seria necesario? (Estoy utilizando mariadb en mi panel de phpmyadmin).

Comment: Como herencia en SQL no conozco, lo que vos planteas son relaciones en tablas, lo cual podes hacer tablas intermedias como lo haces en la Tabla Persona, tenes la tablar persona, con dni, nombre, apellido y despues la tabla empleado y cliente tienen una foreign key a Dni de la tabla Persona, entonces no duplicas campos iguales. Después tenes que evaluar si te conviene dejar los datos en una sola tabla o amerita separar los datos tablas diferentes. Podes hacer un plan de ejecucion con SQL Managemente y ver que es mas rapido, cargandole datos genericos en gran cantidad.

Comment: Yo recomiendo no usar herencia en la capa de persistencia. Posiblemente sea más útil abstraer las entidades como objetos en tu aplicación y diseñar tu BD identificando estas entidades y normalizando sus datos. Por ejemplo, tu tabla Persona tendría un tipo_persona y un ID, un campo ultima_compra que podríá ser NULL para los empleados, Edad, Domicilio, etc.. y así.

Comment: Sobre la herencia por fecha, eso más que herencia es particionamiento por rango. Que es útil cuando cada partición tiene millones de registros. Menos que eso suele bastar con una tabla con todo y una consulta que busque en un intervalo de fecha

Comment: Me gustaria saber, de que documentacion o lugar sacas que hay herencia entra tablas en una base de datos?

Comment: @gbianchi postgresql tuvo esa aberración hasta la versión 10, creo. Así emulaban el particionamiento, creando tablas hijas con INHERITS, junto a un trigger function que mandaba los datos a la tabla hija correspondiente. Los selets iban sobre la tabla padre.

Comment: Claro.. pero me gustaria saber de donde op saco esta informacion.. pq lo que esta pidiendo son simplemente claves foraneas.. pero que las confunda con herencia es gravisimo cuando quiera entender sql

Comment: @RamiroBarone Opino lo mismo, creo que el video que explico esto tenia un concepto erroneo, tambien pienso que son tablas relacionadas, en este caso hice las pruebas, y tener todos los campos en una sola tabla era mas rapido que tenerlas relacionadas, pero teniendo un concepto de fecha, ¿crees que se puedan subdividir tablas por fechas?, me refiero a tener digamos una tabla que almacene todo 2020, y dentro de ella separadas por otras tablas enero, febrero etc,

Comment: Segun la cantidad de registros que tengas, tenes que ver si te conviene hacer indices para que la busqueda sea mas rapida. Pero no me parece ser tu caso, tenes que hablar de cientos de miles de registros para ver el tema de rendimiento.